# File-based conditional steps in Jenkins Pipeline (like Make)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm considering the option to use Jenkins Pipeline to build data ETL pipelines. For the moment, it sounds more attractive, more modern and simpler to use than Make/Makefile.

However, I don't understand if the same Make/Makefile step-triggering behaviour is available, eg, let's say I have `data2.xml` built by the script `csv2xml.sh`, taking `data1.csv` as input: in a Makefile, it's pretty straightforward to declare that `data2.xml` must be built only if it doesn't exist or is older than `data1.csv`.

Is it possible to do the same in Jenkins Pipeline? Or am I looking at the wrong tool?

Answer (score 0):

such steps are available under sh/bat execution, you can deal with your make/makefile as usual , Jenkins will just execute it and give you back results, afterwards inside pipeline you will decide what to do with it, e.g. upload to server or something similar

Comment: No, I don't want to use make from within Jenkins, I want to replace it with Pipelines, but I'd like something to replicate the same semantics, which allows for incremental building of just the files that don't exist yet, or are older than their dependencies.